# No option to submit new build or change submission in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

By accident I submitted an old build after feedback from Apple. I withdrew the feedback but now I cannot send a new build.

My menu for my app looks as follows,

[image]

My app review pane shows "processing" with no option to cancel.

Any advice how to deal with the situation?

Comment: I think there should be option to cancel this current submission after cancelling submission you should be able to create new submission and submit new build in appstoreconnect

Answer (score 0):

Just had to wait to have Apple reject my app and submit again.